# Have problems with the Blender Eve character. Can only modifie one side of the character in sculpt mode

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, sculpting

I have problems with the Rain Character. One half of the character won't react at all in Scuplt Mode and don't understand why.

The Character is available for free here:[image]
https://cloud.blender.org/p/characters/5f04a68bb5f1a2612f7b29da

Thank you very much in advance <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. It has something to do with the Shape Keys. You have to select basic and then go into sculpt mode .
[image]